# Import Lightwave Object LWO

Tags: scripting, add-on

I'm new in Blender, but close to 20 years of experience with Lightwave.
I had read that you can enable LWO import in *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*, but there's no Lightwave import option there.

I found Newtek MDD and enabled it, but LWO still doesn't load into Blender.

https://www.behance.net/gallery/82385749/Vought-F4U-Corsair-CGI

Comment: This add-on doesn't exist in the current versions of Blender. It has been removed as part of the [clean-up of broken and unmaintained add-ons](https://developer.blender.org/T63750).

Answer (score 2):

I keep a copy of Blender 2.79, where it still works, on my desktop to import LWO.

Import, then save as a blend file and open in 2.8x

Answer (score 0):

there is an Addon to do that:
https://github.com/nangtani/blender-import-lwo/releases

Answer (score 0):

I usually export from LW as FBX and then import into Blender (i have 2.80) as FBX, and it retains the information.

I gave up on looking for importers for LWO in other software a long time ago.

Given the status of LW these days I usually look for an in-between, and FBX has been that for many years now.